# Android Studio (studio64.exe) not Working

Tags: android-studio

I am a new user to Android studio. When I try to Open Studio64.exe, it says the error box like in this [Error Message Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8SnR.png) (I am having Windows 7 64-Bit Service Pack-3)

Please can anyone solve this problem? And I tried looking in jre\bin folder and saw that some files are missing. Can anyone post the link for those files? i downloaded the Android studio from developers.android.com as a zip file. ([studio64.exe Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHEm7.png))

Comment: re install it,but anyway,windows 7 is no way a platform for android studio,use windows 10 some day later

Comment: Its okay but I tried installing the same package in my laptop running win 10 but it doesn't work too

Comment: Should try installing the exe extractor?

Comment: yes try installing exe once more,it will uninstall,and then install

Comment: I'll try and inform you

Comment: Now I am not Having My Laptop so i will try it later.